# MixRGB Node Blend Modes: Subtract vs Difference - what's the difference?

Tags: materials, node-editor, color

Okay, I can't believe I never noticed this until today but... the MixRGB node's **Subtract** and **Difference** blend modes both appear to produce the same output.

Start with white and take blue away from it... both blend modes produce yellow.

To specify precisely with hex codes: #ffffff minus #0000ff equals #ffff00 no matter which blend mode is used.

[image]

So pardon my wording but, ***is there any difference?***

Let's consult the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/color/mix_rgb.html#examples):

> **Subtract**
>
> Taking Blue away from white leaves Red and Green, which combined make Yellow. Taking Blue away from Purple leaves Red. Use this to
> desaturate an image. Taking away yellow makes an image bluer and more
> depressing.
>
> **Difference**
>
> It takes out a color. The color needed to turn Yellow into White is Blue. Use this to compare two very similar images to see what had
> been done to one to make it the other; sort of like a change log for
> images. You can use this to see a watermark (see [Watermark images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/color/mix_rgb.html#watermark-images)) you
> have placed in an image for theft detection.

So the descriptions are a little different... but I reiterate: is there any difference?

<sub>(If the answer is that they are identical, that's fine. I just want to know before I go creating a bunch of node setups based on an assumption.)</sub>

Comment: No, they are not producing the same result. It might look like it when you use white as the first color, but change that to red and you will already see a difference.

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting `Color1` to red (#ff0000) and plugged an image into `Color2`. In this configuration there is a clear difference. The best I can explain it though is that **Subtract** takes away non-reds leaving a red and black two-tone image, while **Difference** takes away from red according to what the other colors are, which leaves red where darker areas of `Color2`'s image would be.

Comment: Here is a more technical description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Subtract (Subtract simply subtracts pixel values of one layer with the other. In case of negative values, black is displayed / Difference subtracts the bottom layer from the top layer or the other way around, to always get a non-negative value.)

Comment: @Mentalist Actually, when Color1 is red and you subtract a colorful image, it's not taking away non-reds from the image. All red values of the image are subtracted from the red color, and since the green and blue channels are 0 in Color1, every other color of the image gets subtracted from 0 leaving a negative value (if the node is not clamped) which shows as black.

Comment: I think I get the gist of it. If I have red as `Color1`and I want to invert it to cyan, I should use **Difference**, with white as `Color2`. I someone posts an answer that can be understood intuitively (maybe with some visual examples), I will most likely accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difference is the absolute value of Subtract ie. $|\mathrm{Color1} - \mathrm{Color2}|$. So they will be the same if Color1 is >= Color2.

See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253944) for more.

---

edit: I'll give a small example with grayscale colors.

[image: Subtract vs Difference with grayscale colors]

With Subtract, Color2 is subtracted from Color1.

1. When Color2 is black, you get Color1.
2. As Color2 gets brighter, the output gets darker.
3. When Color2 reaches Color1, you get black.
4. When Color2 is brighter than Color1, it can't get any darker so it just stays black.

Difference is the same except in case 4.

4. (For Difference) When Color2 is brighter than Color1, instead of being stuck at black, it starts getting lighter again.

If Subtract means "subtract Color2 from Color1" then Difference means "subtract the darker from the lighter".

Comment: I don't see "Subtract" mentioned in that answer. Maybe it's a newer blend mode?

Comment: Dunno, it doesn't list them all, I always just check the source code (linked in a comment).

Comment: @Mentalist Well, _Subtract_ is just as the name says, a subtraction, which means Color1 - Color2 <> Color2 - Color1, whereas _Difference_ means |Color1 - Color2| = |Color2 - Color1|.

Comment: So you could think of *Difference* as entry-wise *Distance*?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady No, _Vector Math_ > _Distance_ results in a 1-dimensional value, whereas _MixRGB_ > _Difference_ still results in RGB. In mathematical terms it's (like mentioned above), _Difference_ = abs(Color1 - Color2*Fac) and _Subtract_ = (Color1 - Color2*Fac).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's what "entry-wise" means. Also that's not the right formula for Fac in Difference, Fac lerps between Color1 and |Color1-Color2|.

Comment: @scurest Sorry, I'm no native speaker, I didn't understand what entry-wise meant. And I have no idea what "lerps" means... but if I use a value of _Fac_ < 1 and Color2 is black, then Color1 is not affected by _Fac_. So what do you mean mathematically is the influence of _Fac_ in _Difference_?

Comment: [Lerp = linear interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Programming_language_support). When Fac=0 the output is Color1. When Fac=1 the output is determined by the mode, |Color1-Color2| for Difference. In between it varies linearly between those endpoints.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann An entry is a component, so Vectors and colors have 3 entries. Entry, or component-wise means separately for each. Vector Math > Multiply is an entry-wise operation, because it multiplies V1.x by V2.x, V1.y by V2.y, and V1.z by V2.z and that's it - you would have the same by separating V1 into 3 values, separating V2 into 3 values, using 3 scalar math > multiply nodes, and then combining the results into a vector. Vector Math > Distance **isn't** an entry-wise operation - you can use Subtract > Absolute, but apparently RGB Difference ix node is a single node replacement.

Comment: @scurest If you use _Vector Math_ > _Scale_ on Color2 with the _Fac_ value for scaling, then plug Color1 and the scaled Color2 into a _Vector Math_ > _Subtract_ node and this into a _Vector Math_ > _Absolute_ node, this node setup gets you the exact same color as _MixRGB_ > _Difference_, so what is incorrect with my formula abs(Color1 - Color2*Fac) which does exactly what the _Vector Math_ nodes do?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann For example, take Color1 = Color2 / 2, Then the difference is also Color1, so the output will always be Color1 regardless of Fac (you can test this). But your formula gives abs(1/2 - Fac)*Color2, which at say Fac=1/2 is totally black.

Comment: @scurest So what is the formula behind this? If I use for example white (1, 1, 1) and blue (0, 0, 1) for example no matter which is Color1 or Color2, my formula works. As soon as I change RGB values to something else than 0 or 1, I cannot calculate the result anymore, for example with (1, 0.5, 0.5) and (0, 0, 1).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann (1-Fac)*Color1 + Fac*|Color1-Color2|

Comment: @scurest Okay thanks, have no more time to check that today but it sounds reasonable.  Looks like the factor is working as the _Opacity_ value in Photoshop when using the layer blend mode _Difference_, but I thought the factor would work like the _Fill_ value.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Wow, this is great! In the past I googled how Fill differs from Opacity in Photoshop and I only learned the former doesn't affect effects like shadow, while the latter does. I nodified the formula you described: https://i.imgur.com/UR9Vnbu.png and got the same color in Photoshop with blend mode = difference and Fill = 0.35 (factor used in Blender). So in Photoshop the opacity lerps between layers, and Fill is a color multiplier.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, it seems like that. That's a really cool byproduct of this discussion, now I got formulas for the blend mode in Photoshop. In the past I always read that _Difference_ in PS is calculated |color1 - color2| and read that _Difference_ is one of 8 blend modes where _Opacity_ and _Fill_ behave different (apart from having no influence on effects etc.) - but never an explanation how they affect the blend mode differently.