What does the color blend mode do?
What does the color blend mode in mix shader node do? I've read the documentation, but there is no information about Color blend type. And I don't even know how to google it, because my request looks stupid: blender color mode in mix color.

The Blender docs reference the explanation here in the Krita documentation if that's any help.

It's funny, the manual used to reference Gimp's documentation and now they switched to Krita :D In any case, yeah, blending modes are not unique to Blender you could just google "color blending modes" to find out what that is. It's just various math operations done between pixel values of two images.

Friendship ended with GIMP Now KRITA is my best friend... Take a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253944/60486

If you want to know exactly what the Mix Color mode "Color" does, here is a mathematical explanation:
The color A gets scaled by 1 - Factor. A combination of color B's Hue and Saturation with color A's Value will be scaled by the Factor. The results of these scalings/multiplications are added together to give the final result.
So this setup:

can be recreated mathematically with this node setup (well, actually you can do it with less nodes, I just extended it a bit to show the components a bit better):

